# Retrieve user from database and cast to an user object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to do this:

```
User user = (User)db.Users.Include("Sports").Where(a => a.UserId == currentUser.UserId);
```

But I'm getting a cast error.

How can I retrieve a user from database and cast to an user object ?

SOLUTION:

```
User user = db.Users.Include("Sports").Where(a => a.UserId == currentUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
User user = db.Users.Include("Sports").SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserId == currentUser.UserId);
```

Comment: You need to add a `.FirstOrDefault()` to your LINQ expression - right now, you're getting a **collection** of objects back.... (not a single one)

Comment: To better declare your intentions, you should use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx) instead of `Where` if you expect only a single object to ever fit your predicate. ...Also, what marc_s said. `Where` returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: Now it's working using either SingleOrDefault or FirstOrDefault. Thanks to all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly cast.

```
User user = db.Users.Include("Sports").
              Where(a => a.UserId == currentUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should work, Asssumung `Users` is a Property of Type `DbSet<User>`.

Answer (score 2):

you could try

```
 User user = (from U in db.Users.Include("Sports") where U.UserID == currentUser.UserID select U).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
     var user = (from U in db.Users.Include("Sports") 
where U.UserID == currentUser.UserID select U).Single();
```

Since there should only be one matching userID.

Answer (score 0):

var user = db.Users.Find(currentUser.UserId);

db.Entry(user).Reference("Sports").Load();

Comment: You should explain your answer a bit.